# Use cplex with c++: add conditional constraint

Tags: c++, cplex

I'm new in cplex, I found in python the function: add_indicator_constraint, but in c++ I can't find anything like that. Can someone show me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the example ilofixnet.cpp in CPLEX_Studio201\cplex\examples\src\cpp you can see a good example of indicator constraint in C++

```
// Add logical constraints that require x[i]==0 if f[i] is 0.
      for (IloInt i = 0; i < x.getSize(); ++i)
         model.add(IloIfThen(env, f[i] == 0, x[i] == 0));
```

Comment: Because of the deadline, I found another way to solve the problem. anyway, thank you very much. What I just learned will be useful in the future.